# How to disable the main toolbar in epiphany

Tags: browser

Epiphany has a nice app mode:

```
epiphany --profile myapp -a http://superuser.com
```

But it still displays the main toolbar with url (locked), title, back/forward and reload buttons. I would like to disable them as well, so it really looks like a native app and not a browser window.

The basic settings (non-app mode) do not provide options to configure the toolbars, dconf seems to have some options about icon, text, both, which do not change anything (app mode and normal window). Is there an option or some trick to hide the toolbar completely?